# Full Width Image With Smaller Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have an image break out of a page design to fill the full browser width and scale with resizing in a CMS system like on http://na.sage.com/ca/sage-payment-solutions. They also have text content on the images. That would be great, but is not necessary.
There are sliders like http://www.unitecms.net/joomla-extensions/unite-revolution-slider-responsive/revolution-full-width-demo that can do it for slide shows, but I haven't seen anything to just push out a single image.
The page the CMS output could be like:

```
<body>
 <div>
  <div style="width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
   <div>
    <div>
     Text above image
<img alt="this should span the whole browser width" src="very wide image.jpg">
     Text below image
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

...more or less.

Comment: for img style="width: 100%;"

Comment: Thanks Reza, but that doesn't break out of the 800px container.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this very easily with background: url() on your div. See this for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/4/embedded/result/

Code at:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/

```
.image{
    background: url('http://37.media.tumblr.com/e615708905cc9df81f901c06ae4afe1e/tumblr_n21ltnVLtz1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg');
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
```

What happens is that the div has BLOCK as default view, so it will be stretched through the whole page.

Now, how to add text ON the image? You could just place it inside the div, but for a better control I'd give it absolute positioning. Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/1/

```
.image h2{
    position:absolute;
    top: 125px;
    right:50px;
}
```

Also, if you want to avoid your image to repeat when it's too small, you could do something like this:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/2/

Further more, if you want better control over the content INSIDE the image. You could add an additional div and give it some styling. Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/3/

EDIT:

To make it full screen with no white spaces, make sure to have a "soft reset" of the body. (margin and padding: 0)

Final fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/4/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Unfortunately your solution doesn't break out of the parent div. I have updated the question to show that the container is centered. I changed your fiddle to show at http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/5/ that the image stays inside the container and doesn't stretch the full width of the browser.

Comment: Nice text on the image/div though.

Comment: I am confused on what you want to achieve and on what purpose.

Comment: Is this by any chance what you were trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/7/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/7/

Comment: No. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/TFU9S/8/ ...I want the image to go the full width of the "browser" and not of the div it's in.

Comment: ...oh and I want the image to scale when the browser is enlarged or made smaller.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, what do you want to achieve that you CAN'T do with other methods?

Comment: I want to have the ability to stretch an image the full width of the browser like you see on http://na.sage.com/ca/sage-payment-solutions where they have multiple images the full browser width running down the page while the text is contained in a smaller area. The problem is that the image(s) can only be set in the article editor of WordPress/Joomla and so I can't change the flow of the divs from inside the article editor.

Comment: On the website you pointed out, the images are set WITHIN a div which has basically the same width of the page because its display is set to block by default plus the width:100% of its .image-box class, nothing we didn't cover, both me and other people, on other answers. 
Now, can you give us a practical example of what you are trying to achieve? 
You have a wodpress article editor and would like to <img> and automatically stretch it to full width?

Comment: Yes, the Sage site does it that way. That was only to show how it should look when finished. If you go to the http://www.unitecms.net/joomla-extensions/unite-revolution-slider-responsive/revolution-full-width-demo slider I had mentioned you can see that the slider is able to break out of the template/article dimensions and force the slideshow to the full browser width. that's what I want, just for a single image and not for a full slideshow. I am getting closer at http://jsfiddle.net/X3FxE/2/ but I don't have the adjusting on resize working.

Comment: I have edited my question with my current answer at http://jsfiddle.net/X3FxE/3/  since I can't post an answer myself yet. There you can see what I am looking for. Maybe you know of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Without positioning, first of all set a float on the image to take it out of the document flow, this would set the image width free of the parent width, then, set the image width to 100vw, which means 100% the viewport width.

Apply this CSS to your posted HTML:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
img {
    width:100vw;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/ZGP2E/)**

Comment: Thanks Karim. I didn't know about vw. Unfortunately I wasn't quite clear. The 800px div is centered with "margin: 0 auto;". I have updated the question now. This doesn't work since your sample doesn't break to the left.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ZGP2E/1/ to show the problem that the image isn't left and it extends the image over to the right which makes it scroll.

Answer (score 0):

With some ideas from here and some more research I have now a proof of concept at
http://jsfiddle.net/X3FxE/4/

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    Text above div
    <div id="imgcontainer">
        Text within div - 
        <img  id="imgwide" src="http://www.3dwallhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/248721xcitefun-wide-wallpaper004.jpg" />
        just runs through
    </div>
    Text below div
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function setHeight() {
  var args = setHeight.arguments;
  document.getElementById(args[0]).style.height = document.getElementById(args[1]).clientHeight+'px';
}
function resiz() {setHeight('imgcontainer', 'imgwide');}
resiz();

var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};
addEvent(window, "resize", resiz);
```

I still have to work out how to integrate that into CMS articles for Joomla and WordPress but the concept is ready now.